# Cannot Enable My Graphic Card (ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics)

Tags: drivers, ati

I'm new to Ubuntu. I hve update all my driver after installation and all of the driver was enable except for the graphic driver. I'm using Compaq Presario cq40. Here are the details:

```
 *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RS780M/RS780MN [Radeon HD 3200 Graphics]
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 5
                bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:7000(size=256)
```

When I open `additional drivers` and try to enable the driver it say:

```
Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log
```

I need a help.

Comment: can you add the errors from /var/log/jockey.log ?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8019/how-can-i-enable-ati-open-source-drivers) and [this community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)?

Comment: @nitstorm : I've read that .the first step it says that i have to uninstall the driver but it fails saying :"sh: Can't open /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh". Any idea ?

Comment: @fossfreedom : How do i do that ?

Comment: `gedit /var/log/jockey.log` and copy and paste what you see (or the relevant parts) into an edit of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the blacklist bug? Ubuntu Oneiric has a bug, in that it does not properly blacklist the genric radeon driver, when you install the proprietary one.

Does the workaround described here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/827120 help you?